# npm ERR! Cannot read property '@emotion/react' of undefined

Tags: npm

encounter `npm ERR! Cannot read property '@emotion/react' of undefined` when use `npm ci`

Looking forward to encountering the correct solution
npm version
nodejs version

> node -v
> v14.20.1
> npm -v
> 6.14.17

13 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property '@emotion/react' of undefined
13 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lock-verify/index.js:27:40
13 verbose stack     at Array.forEach ()
13 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lock-verify/index.js:25:25

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can check npm version and nodejs version
check package-lock.json  "lockfileVersion" verison

use nvm to manage node and npm version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0XUs.png)